# How to convert SFM models to Blender on a Mac?

Tags: modeling, export, import

I want to convert some SFM models to Blender but all the conversion tools I can find (i.e. Crowbar) are for Windows only. Is there any way to port SFM models to Blender on a mac?

Answer (score -1):

I know you asked this 8 months ago. but there is a way to install windows on a mac. it will partition your hard drive. it's dual booting. this is done by an official application included in macOS, called Bootcamp assistant. you'll need a 32GB or bigger pendrive, and a copy of windows (which is provided by Apple on the app's website) I've used it a lot. macOS can interact with the partitioned windows part of the hard drive, but it's read-only. (you can only open files from the drive, or copy them to a write and read the drive and modify the copy) unfortunately, windows cant interact with mac. to switch OS hold alt when booting up the PC and you'll see two drives. "windows" and "Macintosh HD" in that order. if you don't hold alt, it automatically boots on windows. I don't know if you can change it.